# Xamarin forms gestures not working with a view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gestures

I'm having some trouble with gestures in xamarin forms.  I've used an example I found from the web that wraps an Image control in a PanContainer which handles panning gestures:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestGestures
{
    public class PanContainer : ContentView
    {
        double x, y;

        public PanContainer ()
        {
            // Set PanGestureRecognizer.TouchPoints to control the 
            // number of touch points needed to pan
            var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer ();
            panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add (panGesture);
        }

        void OnPanUpdated (object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.StatusType) {

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                Content.TranslationX = Math.Max (Math.Min (0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs (Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Max (Math.Min (0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs (Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));    
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                // Store the translation applied during the pan
                x = Content.TranslationX;
                y = Content.TranslationY;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wrapper usage:

```
public HomePageCS ()
{
    Content = new AbsoluteLayout {
        Padding = new Thickness (20),
        Children = {
            new PanContainer {
                Content = new Image {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromFile ("MonoMonkey.jpg"),
                    WidthRequest = 1024,
                    HeightRequest = 768
                }
            }   
        }
    };
}
```

This example works absolutely fine, no problems at all.

The problems start when I replace the image that is wrapped in the PanContainer with a control that inherits from `View` and has a customer renderer for each platform.  When I do this the OnPanUpdated method never gets called.

Does anyone know why this happens on a `View` and is there any workaround to get it to work?

Comment: Instead of putting in the example you downloaded, put your actual code and custom render if you want people to help you.

Comment: Take a look at Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView. It might meet your needs. See example here: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Comment: Rohit, The customer renderer is quite complex and it split over many units.  I think this would just confuse the situation.  I can see that the problem is because of the view so maybe I could create a more simple example.

Comment: theealjohn, I can't do that because my app is a mapping application that needs to respond to swipes in all directions as well as tap and pinch gestures

Comment: You may find the joystick in this sample of use: https://github.com/Clancey/SpiderBot this uses a custom renderer for two circles, and then extends layout<view>
(Keep in mind I've only found your question as on occasion action.completed isn't firing)